# Can I go back and forth in a list just with pointer algebra and remove prev/next pointers?

Tags: c, pointers, struct

So let's say I have a list node like this:

```
struct node{
    data_t data;
    struct node* prev;
    struct node* next;
};
```

I usually travelled through the list by using the prev/next addresses stored in the list.

If I'm not mistaken when I have a `type_t *cursor` and just do `cursor++` it points to the next data area of its type;

so I was wondering if I could just remove prev/next pointers from the struct and travel in the list by adding/subtracting to a
`struct node *cursor`
,to save on allocated memory.

Maybe if i remove the said pointers it is not guaranteed that the nodes will be adjacent to one another in the order they were allocated? Or is there something else in this reasoning that might make errors?

My hope would be that if I malloc ten structs and then take a `struct node* cursor` on the list head's address and do `cursor=cursor+7` I get the 7th node of the list, but maybe I am wrong and doesn't work like that?

Comment: It can be done if you stop using linked list and use arrays as list.

Comment: @MikeCAT but i don't know how much data i will have to store so it has to be dynamic

Comment: @wattbatt you can use `realloc` to change the size of your array, both to add or remove elements

Comment: No you can't remove the pointers. It's exactly as you said. One of the properties of a linked list is that the memory may not (and usually is not) adjacent.

Comment: you can't do pointer arithmetic on linked lists because the nodes are not guaranteed to be memory adjacent, you need to use your `prev` and `next` fields in order to go back and fourth through your linked list

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if your *node* are allocated one by one you cannot go to the next/prev by incr/decr a pointer to one of them because you cannot suppose they are adjacent in memory

> My hope would be that if I malloc ten structs and then take a struct node* cursor on the list head's address and do cursor=cursor+7 I get the 7th node of the list, but maybe I am wrong and doesn't work like that?

you can do that, the advantage is you do not need the prev/next pointer so you only memorize *data* saving place, the time to access an element is also immediate rather than to be on O(n), the disadvantage is when you want to add/remove element(s) because you have to move the ones after.

Note having an array you can also access an element with an index rather than to have a pointer to that element.

The function `realloc` allows to change the size of your dynamic array, both to add or remove elements from its end

Comment: So if I also had to modify the data order, considering list vs array I would have: list more memory less time, while a dynamic array would be less memory more time? In my program i would have to do few reordering so array sounds better like this

Comment: For the memory size for sure the list need more. For the time all depends on the operation you do, some are faster with an array and some with a list. To modify data order it is not so clear to know if faster with an array or a list, that also depends on the size of the data

Answer (score 1):

> "*Can I go back and forth in a list just with pointer algebra and remove prev/next pointers?*"
>
> "*Maybe if I remove the said pointers it is not guaranteed that the nodes will be adjacent to one another in the order they were allocated?*"

You can go back and forth if you have an static or dynamically allocated array of `struct node`. Then it is guaranteed that each element is stored in subsequent order and you can use pointer arithmetic.

Unfortunately, in the most cases when using linked lists, this is not the case, as each node is allocated separately.

> "*So I was wondering if I could just remove prev/next pointers from the struct and travel in the list by adding/subtracting to a `struct node *cursor`, to save on allocated memory.*"

As said above, only when you allocated an array of `node`. Else if each and every `node` is allocated separately, then you can't or better said it is undefined behavior by any attempt.

The C standard prohibits incrementing a pointer after one past an aggregate or an scalar object.

Not to mention that of course dereferencing a pointer, which points after an aggregate or scalar object, is also not allowed.

> "*My hope would be that if I `malloc()` ten structs and then take a `struct node*` cursor on the list head's address and do `cursor = cursor + 7` I get the 7th node of the list, but maybe I am wrong and doesn't work like that?*"

It works only if you `malloc()` all ten structures by one call to `malloc`. Then the structures are stored adjacent in memory and pointer arithmetic guaranteed to work.

Also note that you need to use `cursor = cursor + 6;` to get to the `7`th node, not `cursor = cursor + 7;` as indexing starts at `0`, not `1`.